# Cosine series for Dirac Delta comb

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, distribution-theory

I am learning a bit about distributions and came across the following...

In "Theory of Distributions, a nontechnical introduction" by Richards and Youn there is a formula with no explanation in the introduction. It states that as a distribution the following makes sense:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta''(x-2\pi n)=\frac{-1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\cos(nx) $$

Could someone please explain why the singularities don't pose an issue- how does one make sene of this summation? i am most curious about the singularity when the $n$ on the LHS=0. is this a known cosine representation of $\delta''$?
thanks

Comment: There are two steps here. First, the Fourier transform of a dirac comb (without the derivatives) is a Dirac comb in frequency space, which, when converted back to physical space, is a sum of cosines with a different scaling (in particular the $n^2$ is not there). For details on this see here: https://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/the-dirac-comb-and-its-fourier-transform.html
Second, to get the derivatives, you do the standard move of multiplying by a test function and integrating by parts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives_of_the_Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: (Regarding singularities and convergence) For the sums to make sense, one should view the objects being summed not as functions with defined pointwise values, but rather as linear functionals which act on smooth compactly supported test functions. Convergence of the sum is defined with respect to the topology of the continuous dual space of the space of test functions. Here the convergence is straightforward to show, because the compact support of a test function implies only a finite number of $\delta''$ functions will be active, so only a finite number of terms in the sum will be nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality means that for all $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$,
$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta''(x - 2\pi n)\phi(x)\,dx = -\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} n^2\cos(nx)\phi(x)\,dx.$$
Applying the definition of differentiation (integration by parts) and $\delta$ yields
$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\phi''(2\pi n) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^2\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(nx)\phi(x)\,dx.$$
The left hand side makes sense since only finitely many terms of the sum are nonzero due to $\phi$ having compact support. On the right hand side, we notice $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos(nx)\phi(x)\,dx$ is essentially $\text{Re } \hat{\phi}(n)$, and since $\phi$ is smooth and compactly supported, $\hat{\phi}$ is a Schwartz function, so the sum on the right is absolutely convergent.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i really like the method for the rhs, i do have some questions though. (1) why is it $\sum \int \cos\phi$ and not $\int \sum \cos\phi$, does the order not matter (and why)? (2) recapitulating the argument for rh: the integral $\int \cos \phi$ is real part of FT of $\phi$ (which exists b/c $\phi$ is schwartz or $C^\infty_c$), but why is the sum convergent? is it b/c it is bound by some energy estimate (parsival/plancherel)?

Comment: (1) The identity is a sum converging in the topology of the space of distributions. This is the only way to make sense of it since the left hand side is an infinite sum of distributions. When you evaluated a sum of functions on an argument, you sum the individual applications of each function to the argument. (2) Since $\phi$ is Schwartz, $\hat{\phi}$ is also Schwartz (this is a well known fact), so $\hat{\phi}$ and all it's derivatives decay faster than any power of $(1 + \xi^2)^{n/2}$.